# openCart 3 - How to get total price at checkout page?

Tags: php, sorting, opencart-3

I need to find out how to get total price at checkout page (**confirm.php**) to plus my own price.
I need to check total and if it's more then 5K then delivery service is free, otherwise delivery service has a fixed price.

```
$this->$cart->getTotal(); // it returns totals not including coupons
$this->$cart->getSubTotal(); // it returns products totals not including coupons
```

Does anyone know how to get total including coupons/vouchers...?

Comment: You can see active total extension and then get totals array by calling each getTotal method from them

Comment: And get your desired data by calculations from that array

Comment: @ArunVishwakarama Could you show me any example please?

Comment: You can check confirm.php

Comment: Where it getting total type extension by function

Comment: @ArunVishwakarama though I didn't understand what you was trying to say, thank you anyway

Comment: Ok let me add answer for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Sort a Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-a-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->load->model('setting/extension');
$sort_order = array();
$results = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('total');
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    $sort_order[$key] = $this->config->get('total_' . $value['code'] . '_sort_order');
}
array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $results);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($this->config->get('total_' . $result['code'] . '_status')) {
        $this->load->model('extension/total/' . $result['code']);
        // We have to put the totals in an array so that they pass by reference.
        $this->{'model_extension_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($total_data);
        }
    }
$sort_order = array();
foreach ($totals as $key => $value) {
    $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
}
array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $totals);
```

here in $totals you will have all total data, and you can use that to get total as desired by calculating that array values

This you will fine in confirm.php

Just print $totals and check then you got the data and calculate total with voucher too by adding both data